# What is the ExtJs xtype for LiveSearchGridPanel

Tags: extjs4.2

I have been trying to include a LiveSearchGridPanel into a Panel along with a grid and a slider.  I have been able to find the xtype for grid and slider but cannot find the xtype for LiveSearchGridPanel.  getXType returns undefined and getXTypes is not helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a UX component we have to include the path of the view file also in our app.js.

Add below to include a ux component in your app : eg ux.Router

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'Ext.ux.Router': 'lib/Router.js'
    }
});
```

And then using in our app..

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'App',
  autoCreateViewport: true,
  requires: [
    'Ext.ux.Router'
  ],
  controllers: [
    'Home', 
    'Users'
  ],
  views: [
    'Viewport',
    'user.List',
    'user.Form'
  ],
  routes: {
    '/': 'home#index',
    'users': 'users#list',
    'users/:id/edit': 'users#edit'
  }
});
```