# How to use a ux component in Extjs CMD Application?

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I want to use [Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel) in my view. 
Currently I am setting gridPanel as

```
xtype:'app-main',
    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },
    layout: 'absolute',
    autoScroll : true,
    resizable:true,
    items: [


        {
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
            itemId: 'myGrid',
            plugins: [rowEditing],
            reference: 'reqGridpanel',
            listeners: {
                'selectionchange': function(view, records) {
                this.down('#deleteRecord').setDisabled(!records.length);
                }
            },
```

I want to use liveSearchGridPanel or Live Search feature in my grid panel, can anyone tell me that how can I use it? 
Like Currently I am setting 'xtype' property to use a component, how can I use ux component?

I have seen this question [What is the ExtJs xtype for LiveSearchGridPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328293/what-is-the-extjs-xtype-for-livesearchgridpanel) but I am not able to understand the answer.

This is my directory structure

[image: My App Directory Structure]

Kindly help.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LiveSearchGridPanel has no xtype. You must create it via Ext.create("Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel");

Checkout the [example](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/grid/live-search-grid.html), where you can see howto create the LiveSearchGridPanel

If you use the sencha cmd application structure it should work out of the box. Otherwise you have to specify the path to the ux folder manually via [Ext.Loader.setPath](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-setPath). If you not use the sencha cmd application structure I would recommend to create a folder "ux" and copy all the sencha ux classes you need into that folder. You find the sencha ux classes in ext/src/ux.

Example with direct creation of the LiveSearchGridPanel

```
{
    xtype : 'app-main',
    controller : 'main',
    viewModel : {
        type : 'main'
    },
    layout : 'absolute',
    autoScroll : true,
    resizable : true,
    items : [
        Ext.create("Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel", {
            x : 10,
            y : 10,
            itemId : 'myGrid',
            plugins : [rowEditing],
            reference : 'reqGridpanel',
            listeners : {
                'selectionchange' : function (view, records) {
                    this.down('#deleteRecord').setDisabled(!records.length);
                }
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: I understand your point but can you show me that what changes I have to make in code to make this work?

Comment: Please post your folder structure, then I can give you an example.

Comment: i have posted my directory structure in my question

Comment: well you are using the default sencha cmd application structure. I added a code example.

Comment: Thanks it is working, though I am facing another error which is 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isBufferedStore' of undefined

Which is due to store, though I have registered it in Application's Launch function.
It was working fine before this LiveSearch thing, 
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: how do you set the store on the LiveSearchGridPanel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75107/discussion-between-adam-gilly-and-simon-hoss).

Comment: Do note that the LiveSearchGridPanel example will not work for all the records if the grid has bufferedRenderer = true (it's enabled by default) and you've a large number of records in the grid

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create a new view like MyApp.view.grid.LiveSearchGrid in folder app/view/grid and then define like this:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.grid.LiveSearchGrid", {
    extends: 'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel',
    xtype: 'MyLiveSearchGrid'
});
```

and in your component:

```
{
   xtype : 'app-main',
   controller : 'main',
   viewModel : {
       type : 'main'
   },
   layout : 'absolute',
   autoScroll : true,
   resizable : true,
   x : 10,
   y : 10,

   items : [{
       xtype: 'MyLiveSearchGrid',
       itemId : 'myGrid',
       plugins : [rowEditing],
       reference : 'reqGridpanel',
       listeners : {
           scope: this,
           selectionchange : function (view, records) {
              this.down('#deleteRecord').setDisabled(!records.length);
           }
       }
   }]
```

}

and very important, if you use Sencha CMD (which I hope you do), don't forget to put the 'ux' package in the requirements, otherwise it won't work.